# Why am I not able to add two integers with XOR, AND and left shift?

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, xor

I tried running this on [LeetCode problem Sum of Two Integers](https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-of-two-integers/)

```
class Solution:
    def getSum(self, a: int, b: int) -> int:
        while b:
            withoutcarry = (a ^ b)
            b = (a & b) << 1
            a = withoutcarry
        return a
```

It is running correctly for the following test cases and in total 8 out of 26 of LeetCode's testcases:

> a, b = 1, 2
>
> a, b = 2, 3

And a few others but not for this one:

> a, b = -1, 1

It exceeds the time limit.

I tried running the following code with a `mask` variable:

```
class Solution:
    def getSum(self, a: int, b: int) -> int:
        mask = 0xffffffff
        while b:
            sum_ = (a ^ b) & mask
            carry = ((a & b) << 1) & mask
            a = sum_
            b = carry
        if (a >> 31) & 1:
            return ~(a ^ mask)
        return a
```

And it was able to pass all 3 testcases I listed earlier and in total 20 out of 26 of LeetCode's testcases but failed on:

> a, b = -1, 0
>
> Its output for that was:
>
> 4294967295

Then I tried the following code:

```
class Solution:
    def getSum(self, a: int, b: int) -> int:
        mask = 0xffffffff

        while b != 0:
            tmp = (a & b) << 1
            a = (a ^ b) & mask
            b = tmp & mask

        if a > mask // 2:
            return ~(a ^ mask)
        else:
            return a
```

This time it worked and passed all testcases but I don't know why it works.

Comment: The question in the subject and the question at the end of your post are different. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @trincot My quesiton is why are the first two code snippets not working but the third is.

Comment: I guess you *know* what you did when you introduced the `mask` variable, right? Can you explain? I guess you also had reasons to create the third version. Can you explain what they were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempted solution isn't designed to deal with negative numbers at all, and it fails as soon as any are introduced. The main reason for this is that Python's "long" integer data type is able to support an unlimited bit size. The "xor to add, then repeat if there's any bits to carry" algorithm you're using tries to repeat forever when you add to a negative number to get a positive one. With a fixed bit-width, you'd eventually overflow off the end of the data type after clearing the sign bit, and so the loop would stop.

For instance, if your integers were only four bits long, adding `-1` and `1` would go through these values for `a` and `b`:

```
a=0b1111 b=0b0001
a=0b1110 b=0b0010
a=0b1100 b=0b0100
a=0b1000 b=0b1000
a=0b0000 b=0b0000  # after << overflows, the loop stops here since `b` is zero
```

However, Python's integers don't ever overflow, so in that "last" step you'd end up with `0b10000` for `b`, and `a` would still have an unlimited number of leading `1`s, and you'd keep carrying that bit upwards forever without ever reaching the sign bit and the end of the loop.

The second version of your code tries to fix the overflow issue by imposing a `mask` on the values. The flaw it has is that if `a` is initially negative and `b` is initially zero, the loop never runs, and so the mask never gets applied to `a`. This leaves `a` still negative, while the rest of the code expects all `a` values to be positive at the end. This leads the code that tries to fix values with a sign bit set to do the wrong thing, and inappropriately invert the negative value back into a positive one.

The third version of the code changes the check that tests for values that should be inverted more carefully, and so works as intended. It still lets negative numbers through unmasked if `b` is zero, but it doesn't incorrectly re-invert them into positive values.

You can make the second version of your code work as intended too if you unconditionally apply the mask to `a` at the start of the function, rather than only in the loop:

```
class Solution:
    def getSum(self, a: int, b: int) -> int:
        mask = 0xffffffff
        a &= mask                                    # fix is here
        while b:
            sum_ = (a ^ b) & mask
            carry = ((a & b) << 1) & mask
            a = sum_
            b = carry
        if (a >> 31) & 1:
            return ~(a ^ mask)
        return a
```

Now, all the `a` values will be masked (turning negative values into positive values), and the bit check at the end will correctly identify which results should be considered negative.